# Sound themes stopped working after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have upgraded my Ubuntu install from 11.10 to 12.04 using the Update Manager. My sound card is working fine. I'm able to get sound and I've verified that the microphone works too, but my sound **themes** are not working. For example, when I login, the Ubuntu login sound is not played. Could someone help me figure out how to re-enable it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. It's the decision of Canonical to disable the start up sound by default. May be you can enable it from the start up configuration dialog.

EDIT: There's a package which produces sound event upon login and logout: gnome-session-canberra

Comment: I found 2 credible sources to your answer:
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/ubuntu-12-04-login-sound-to-be-disabled-by-default/
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/ubuntu-12-04-login-sound-to-be-disabled-by-default/

The first source is a bit old (back from Dec. 2011), but I believe this is to be true. The second explains a work-around that I've tried. It works, but it should also specify the -V switch with a value of at least 5.

Comment: I just realized I put the same link in twice. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966840 and http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enable-startup-login-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html#more-13192 are other links I meant to include in my original comment.